# Paste data in a specific row, depending on the number in column 43 (AQ)

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, paste

My Problem seems simple but i'm just not able to solve it alone. My VBA Code copies Data, based on a Filter and past it to another Workbook, starting in Row 1. What i want to change now is, that the Code checks the Number in Column 43 (AQ) from every Row he copies and paste the Row into the Row that matches that Number. For Example: If the Number 7 stands in AQ than the Row should be pasted in row 7. If the Number 3 stands there, it should be pasted into Row 3. In between some Numbers are not included so it can be, that some Rows in between are staying empty.

My intially Code to Copy/Paste data, that worked, was this one.

```
Sub SG7Stundenplan()

SG7Stundenplan


    Sheets("Gruppenplanung").Select
    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Range("A2").Select
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="SG 7", Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("3:100").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Open "R:\BINplus\Langenthal\Stammgruppen\Stammgruppe 7\Stammgruppe 7_Unterrichtspläne Test.xlsm"
    Worksheets("Stammdaten").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("Stammgruppe 7_Unterrichtspläne Test.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
    
    
    End Sub
```

I allready tried to create something new but i failed till now. Im pretty sure you need to copy the Rows singulary to put that trick off.

```
Sub SG7Stundenplan()

Dim Zelle As Range
Workbooks.Open "R:\BINplus\Langenthal\Stammgruppen\Stammgruppe 7\Stammgruppe 7_Unterrichtspläne Test.xlsm"
For Each Zelle In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Gruppenplanung").UsedRange.Columns(19)
If Zelle.Text = "SG 7" Then
    Zelle.EntireRow.Copy
    Workbooks("Stammgruppe 7_Unterrichtspläne Test.xlsm").Worksheets("Stammdaten").Cells(Zelle.Offset(43 - Zelle.Column).Value, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
Next
Workbooks("Stammgruppe 8_Unterrichtspläne Test.xlsm").Close True

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for checking this Post and think about it. Your a great Community that allready helped me a lot.

Sincerely,

David from Switzerland

Answer (score 0):

here is my best attempt at your problem.

My Input Sheet:

[image]

My Code:

```
Sub copyData()

    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open("c:\Desktop\Destination.xlsx")
    Dim dest As Worksheet: Set dest = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim lastRow As Integer: lastRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim lastCol As Integer: lastCol = src.Cells(1, src.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim r As Integer, sendRow As Integer
    For r = 2 To lastRow
        sendRow = src.Cells(r, 1).Value
        src.Range(src.Cells(r, 1), src.Cells(r, lastCol)).Copy Destination:=dest.Range(dest.Cells(sendRow, 1), dest.Cells(sendRow, 1))
    Next r

End Sub
```

My Output:

[image]

Good Luck!